# Exchange server 2010 setup exits after copying setup files

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server which I have demoted from a domain controller because I wanted it to be part of another domain, which was looked after by another domain controller. I did this and then made the server join that other domain. The server already had Exchange Server 2010 installed and working on it. Since I changed domains I am unable to get onto the Exchange Management Console getting the attached error. I have tried logging in as different domain users all with the "Exchange Organization Administrator" membership. The server running the domain controller for the new domain is an SBS2008 server. Any ideas how to resolve this?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyeDH.png)

Comment: Does anybody ever do any research or reading before they do things? What made you think this was a supported operation? It isn't. Wipe and rebuild.

Comment: Hi @joeqwerty. Thanks for the response. I did a few days research on this online. I'm coming from a Linux developer background so it's a bit of a challenge this one. I thought this post might get me at least give me some feedback as to how far wrong i'm going - which it has. The fact that I didn't find anything telling me it _wasn't_ a supported operation made me think it might be a supported operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you have done is not supported and will break Exchange. You have no other option than to wipe and rebuild the machine.

You cannot take Exchange from one domain and add it to another one. Exchange is not a standalone application, it is heavily tied in with Active Directory.

Furthermore it is not supported to run DCPROMO on a machine with Exchange installed. If you don't want the machine to be a domain controller then you have to remove Exchange from it first, then DCPROMO it.

If there is data on it then you could try adding it back to the original domain to see if Exchange will come up then. Otherwise it will have to be a wipe and recover in to the original domain, remount the databases, extract the content then remove Exchange, wipe and rebuild in to the new domain, then install Exchange 2010 SP3. You will also need Exchange 2010 CALs as the SBS 2008 CALs will not cover it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Sembee. At least I have a better idea of what I'm dealing with now. I am a linux developer with very little knowledge of Microsoft Server environments. I have been somewhat thrown in the deep end and after a few days research online I am not much wiser on the subject than I was.

Comment: My goal is to set up the two Windows Server hosts with an Exchange instance each but under a single domain. Then to do a similar thing but under two different domains but a single Organisation. I have struggled to find online resources to solidify my understanding of AD and Exchange enough to attempt this (as you can probably tell!). The intention is to see how Exchange Journaling behaves with both situations in order to test it with some software we are developing and come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: Would you have any advice as to which resources might lead me to get a firmer understanding that I might achieve this? Thanks again.

Comment: Exchange orgs boundaries are the forest. Therefore two WINDOWS domains within the same org isn't possible, unless they are both members of the same Forest. 
If you just want to test two servers sending email to each other, then just setup two new forests and domains, then install Exchange in both. Create a Send Connector in each for the other domain and send away.